# javascript async/await version versus Promise version of function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

I implemented a function using async and it doesn't work.  It always resolves immediately and `result` is always undefined.

Here is the original async version:

```
async function validateOne(item, type, state) {
  const validation = VALIDATIONS[type]
  const result = !(await validation.check(state[item.name].value, state))
  return result || validation.message
}
```

I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working so I rewrote it using a Promise and it works fine.

```
function validateOne(item, type, state) {
  const validation = VALIDATIONS[type]
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    validation.check(state[item.name].value, state).then(result =>
      resolve(result || validation.message)
    )
  })
}
```

I'm confused because in my mind these two implementations should be identical (clearly they are not).  Hopefully it is something obvious, thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: FWIW, you don't need `new Promise` here: you can just return the code starting from `validation.check`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `async function` contains an unnecessary logical not `!` operator. Try:

```
async function validateOne(item, type, state) {
  const validation = VALIDATIONS[type]
  const result = await validation.check(state[item.name].value, state)
  return result || validation.message
}
```

Alternatively, this can be shortened to:

```
async function validateOne(item, type, state) {
  const validation = VALIDATIONS[type]
  return (await validation.check(state[item.name].value, state)) || validation.message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had a typo where one version was negating result and the other wasn't!!  They are in fact, apart from that typo, identical!